# What size replacement brake pads for the Brompton?

Tags: brakes, maintenance, replacement, brompton

What size brake pads are needed to replace the brake pads on a Brompton bicycle?

The brake pads on my Brompton bicycle are getting thin, and I would like to buy a replacement pair. There is no Brompton dealer in my country, so I'd like to just go to a bike shop and purchase brake pads, but I'm not sure which pads I should ask for that will "fit" the brompton.

What size brake pads should I buy to replace my brompton's brake pads?

Comment: If going to your local bike shop, why not take either an existing pad in for them to compare, or even the bike?

Comment: Welcome to Bike Exchange. If you could post a picture of your current pads (edit your question and add the pictures) it would be very helpful in you getting a good answer.

Comment: Well, I'm not just asking for me, but I'm asking so this question/answer is available for all Brompton owners who google this question. So, if some years/models of Bromptons have different size pads than others, then I think all should be listed in the answer.

Comment: And, adding to Ted's comment, while many people do not have or know the details of Bromptons, they would recognize Shimano-compatible road brake pads instantly. A picture would have really been helpful here. I did not even know whether Bromptons use road brakes or V-brakes but from a picture it would have been clear immediately.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield,  Again, if going to the bike shop let them tell you what you need and then post the answer.  Sorry, might be a bit blunt but maybe you're over thinking this?

Answer (score 7):

Brompton brake pads are made using Shimano Road specifications. So any pad compatible with Shimano Road brakes will work.

Difficult to find "evidence" for this claim though (because of course, neither Shimano or Brompton would care about mentioning it), except on "community-driven websites" (reddit, forums) where members are claiming to use Shimano pads on their Bromptons. The pad featured on the brake pad set from Brompton (in olliebulle's answer) is a SwissStop Flash Pro, that is also Shimano road compatible.

[EDIT] This question reminded me that the brake pads of my Brompton were due for a replacement. So I went to a shop to request new shoes (pads in fact). Here's a picture of the original brake pads, and Shimano Road compatible pads.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Brompton can sell parts directly to the consumer. Here is the [complete brake pad set](https://us.brompton.com/shop/parts/brake-pads-set?color=black) you can buy on their online store. The length of the pads is 54 mm. The link points to the US website, but you can change the country to match yours (if available).

You do not need to buy the complete brake pad set (brake pads + brake pad holders) though. You normally only need to swap the brake pads (the rubber part) and get to keep the brake pad holders.

The brakes suggested by Brompton are from [SwissStop](https://www.swissstop.ch/brakepads/rimbrakes/). You could go to a bike shop and ask them for replacement pads of the same brand since you would want to reuse the pad holders. Brompton also suggests using the BXP series for their e-bikes for better braking power.

After changing worn brake pads, you usually need to readjust your brake calipers since the new pads will be much thicker than the old ones. You can try to give a bit of slack to your brake cable to increase the space between the brake pads and the rim by screwing in the barrel adjuster at your brake lever.

Comment: International shipping and delivery is not easy or an option in many places. Are you suggesting that you must use Brompton brake pads on a Brompton? They're not a standard size?

Comment: I edited my answer to give more details. Can you confirm that your brake pads are the same as shown in the link I shared?

Comment: So any brake pad that's marked as "54 mm" should work? Is that width or height? Are all brake pads the same in one dimension? What about thickness, does that matter?

Comment: Brake pads need to be compatible with the brake pad holders, so not any 54 mm brake pads would work. 54 mm is the width. Brake pads can have different dimensions. There is no strict standard for that. Thicker pads would technically last longer if made with the same material as thinner ones, but this size is not usually looked at for compatibility purposes.

Comment: That being said, road bike brake pad holders seem to come in two designs: Shimano design that everyone except Campagnolo is copying (the one with the small screw) and Campagnolo (without the screw). There's a very good chance that Shimano compatible pads fit these.